# Fetching MySQL data from AngularJS UI

Tags: php, angularjs, tomcat

I have just worked in the front-end part alone. So I am not sure how to connect or fetch data from a database. If I am using a tomcat server will I be able to do that using PHP?
I am thinking of creating the project in eclipse. I am not sure how to connect that with PHP either.

Answer (score 0):

if you will use Spring as back-end than you need to create model, controller and DAO. Also, you have to create connection to DB. In controller, you have to create method that will call query from DB. After you've created back-end you have to call http.get method inside of js.

e.g.:

[image: example of controller,model and dao]

```
$http.get('/user/retrieve/' + $scope.authorization.userName).success(function(data) {
                        $rootScope.getName = data;
                    })
                    .error(function(data){
                        $rootScope.getName = $scope.authorization.userName;
                    });

                }
```

After you've created http get method, if call was successful data won't be empty, so you can store it into `$scope` variable.
To show values of `$scope` just put double curly brackets around name of `$scope` like this `{{ getName }}`

There are plenty of tutorials how to get data from mysql using Spring or php.
I'm giving you some insight by posting link of tutorial: http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-mvc-4-angularjs-example/

Hope this will help you!